# How can I properly display a much readable output using sorting?

Tags: swift, sorting, struct

The output of my code is all good, it is already sorted, but the problem is that, it contains some garbage value that I do not need, I will provide the example output of it.

Here is my code:

```
struct Student {
    var id: Int = 0;
    var name: String = String();
    var course: String = String();
    var GPA: Float = 0.0;
}

let student = [
    Student(id: 201520032, name: "Ton Agnis", course: "BSITWMA", GPA: 3.69),
    Student(id: 201620122, name: "Juan Cruz", course: "BSCSSE", GPA: 2.23),
    Student(id: 201723214, name: "Pedro Sy", course: "BSITAGD", GPA: 2.87),
    Student(id: 201418492, name: "Phot xPro", course: "BSCPE", GPA: 3.99)
]

func stud(get studs:[Student]){

    print("Student No.\t\tID\t\tName\t\t\tCourse\t\tGPA")
    for i in 0...studs.count - 1{
        print("Student \(i+1) \t \(student[i].id)\t\(student[i].name)\t\t\(student[i].course)\t\t\(student[i].GPA)")
    }
}

let x = student.sorted{ $0.GPA < $1.GPA }

stud(get: student)

print(x)
```

[Here is the Output of the Given Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tzLB.png)

As you can see the output displays some values that is not needed.

What I want to be displayed is a better readable sorted of values given.

Thank You!

Comment: Which are the values that are not needed, sorry?

Comment: This is not a sorting issue.

Comment: [__lldb_expr_195. <- This one.

Comment: @Tonzkie, declare that `Student` conforms to [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) and define `description` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function stud is already printing your student array in a formatted way.

Remove `print(x)` at the end of the code you posted to get a clean output.

Edit:

Also if I understand correctly your needs, you want to print the sorted list of students by GPA. (x in your code)

You can do it by passing `x` to the `stud` function and by fixing the stud function to use the function parameter instead of student var.

```
struct Student {
  var id: Int = 0;
  var name: String = String();
  var course: String = String();
  var GPA: Float = 0.0;
}

let student = [
  Student(id: 201520032, name: "Ton Agnis", course: "BSITWMA", GPA: 3.69),
  Student(id: 201620122, name: "Juan Cruz", course: "BSCSSE", GPA: 2.23),
  Student(id: 201723214, name: "Pedro Sy", course: "BSITAGD", GPA: 2.87),
  Student(id: 201418492, name: "Phot xPro", course: "BSCPE", GPA: 3.99)
]

func stud(get studs:[Student]){

  print("Student No.\t\tID\t\tName\t\t\tCourse\t\tGPA")
  for i in 0..<studs.count {
    print("Student \(i+1) \t \(studs[i].id)\t\(studs[i].name)\t\t\(studs[i].course)\t\t\(studs[i].GPA)")
  }
}

let x = student.sorted{ $0.GPA < $1.GPA }

stud(get: x)
```

Comment: Thank You! I've fixed it following this step. How come that simple step didn't go through my head. Haha.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your custom classes conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol (add a single computed variable, `description`, of type `String`) then when you print one of those objects it displays nicely formatted.

You could use the formatting of your print statement with tabs as the starting point.